# displaying accented letters in TextView and Spinner controls

Tags: android, textview, android-spinner, diacritics

I have a list of people's names that originally came from a database on a Windows system. It gets transferred to my Android app in an XML file sent over the network.

My problem is that some of the names include accented characters. For example, one name contains an o with an acute accent.

I need to be able to display these names, with their accents, in both a textView and a Spinner control. In my first version, I did nothing and the accented character appeared as a black diamond containing a question mark. I then tried converting all accented letters to their HTML escape versions, for example replacing the o acute with &oacute;. I had hoped that this would be translated back to the correct accented character at the Android end but it wasn't. The string &oacute; appeared in my Android app controls.

Is there any simple way I can display a string that potentially includes accents in my Android app, with those accents correctly displayed? Note that I have control over both the Windows end and the Android end so I can modify the format of the XML file sent from Windows to Android if necessary. I would rather not have to tinker with fonts if it can be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried `textView.setText("ó")` and I did not see any problem.

You could try a test like:

```
try {
    byte[] strByte = "ó".getBytes("UTF-8");
    String myStr = new String(strByte, "UTF-8");
    textView.setText(myStr);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This also worked for me.

Comment: Sorry, I only just saw this. I thought this web site would alert me to answers. I managed to get it to work using &oacute; if I set the textView like this:
        target.setText(Html.fromHtml(newText), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I only just saw the response. I thought StackOverflow would alert me by email when a response came in.
I managed to fix the problem using &oacute; and setting the textView like this:

```
    target.setText(Html.fromHtml(newText), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Whether setting the literal works depends, I think, on the font used. The original string came from a Windows PC so I wonder if it was using a different encoding. Anyway, the &oacute; works as described above so I am happy now.
Thanks again for your interest.